How to switch a specific system setting programmatically
I would like to be able to switch a specific setting on and off without the need to enter the system settings each time.
In particular, the "disable while typing" setting for the touchpad is extremely useful to have while writing, but whenever there is the need to press a key while moving the pointer it will make the system release the mouse, which can be annoying for certain tasks.
Is there a way to switch this setting on and off by, say, setting up a shortcut to activate a proper script or something of the sort? I have found no reference to this effect thus far.
System is Kubuntu 22.04, with Plasma version 5.24.7
Thanks in advance
